# Remove rct1 macro from codebase in microsoft visual studio 10

Tags: c++, windows, msbuild

I'm porting an application from Linux to Windows, and one of my variables, 'rct1', seems to clash with a macro that is coming from somewhere in Windows.  I can't find any information on this - is there a way to disable this macro being defined?

Comment: Is there a reason `#undef rtc1` isn't sufficient?

Comment: #undef also works - I just am not familiar with C preprocessor commands.

Comment: @Nathaniel : Perhaps you should correct your question's title then... ;-]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in `Dlgs.h` in the Windows SDK.

So add `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before all `#include <windows.h>` so you don't bring in `Dlgs.h`.